# I keep on getting incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried everything but cannot understand why am I getting incorrect syntax near ')'.  I though this query should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.CustomerID,
                dbo.v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.Name,
                dbo.v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.AccountNumber,
                dbo.v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.City,
                dbo.v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.State,
                dbo.v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.Profile
FROM dbo.v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_PUSH_CustomerContacts ON dbo.v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.CustomerID = dbo.tbl_PUSH_CustomerContacts.CustomerID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE (v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.CustomerID LIKE '%221200%')
  OR (v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.AccountNumber LIKE '%221200%') (v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.State COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS IN
                                                               (SELECT STATE
                                                                FROM tbl_PUSH_Users_States
                                                                WHERE UserID = 'dhudgens'))
ORDER BY v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.Name
```

It seems the problem is at the end here:

(v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.State COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS IN
                                                               (SELECT STATE
                                                                FROM tbl_PUSH_Users_States
                                                                WHERE UserID = 'dhudgens'))

Comment: OR missing, between 2:nd and 3:rd WHERE condition.

Comment: Where? where am I missing the where condition?

Comment: Between the brackets here -> `LIKE '%221200%') (v_`

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I am so dumb....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
OR (v_PUSH_CUSTOMER_MASTER.AccountNumber LIKE '%221200%') (...
                                                          ^
```

This is the problem, you are missing an `AND` or `OR` in your `WHERE` conditions